# Storing regular expressions in MySQL database table and maching against them

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a very interesting task, which I don't know how to implement.

I need to store many regular expressions in a database table, and need to be able to find which of them matches the given string.

For example:

```
id | regexp
---|-------------
1  | ^hello world$
2  | ^I have [0-9] flowers&
3  | ^some other regexp$ 
4  | ^and another (one|regexp)$
```

And I need to find which of those expressions matches string "I have 5 flowers". Of course I can **SELECT * FROM table** and loop through an expressions matching them one by one in PHP, but this would be horrible for server to handle.

Can I somehow index this table or use a special SQL query to handle this task?

I'll appreciate any answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
select * from table where $your_string RLIKE regexp
```

[mysql regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html)

Comment: Thank you, I used RLIKE before, but didn't think of switching arguments :)

Comment: What kind of index should I use, to fit best this situation? Just index the regexp column?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'some stuff' REGEXP `regexp`;
```

Unfortunately there is no way to use indexes with queries that use regexps.